# Provide RSS feed for questions with >n votes or replies?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, answers, feed, voting

I'd be interested in an RSS feed for questions with at least a certain number of votes or replies. This might be implemented as a GET parameter appended to any feed URL.

For example, the following feed might return PHP articles with at least 20 votes:
stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/php?v=20

The following feed might return jQuery articles with at least 15 replies:
stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/jquery?r=20

This would purposely reduce the list of PHP articles for users interested in reading, but not necessarily replying to, specific topics.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we do now have much better tag-based feed support:

[Any way to get an RSS feed of 'newest' tagged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10140/any-way-to-get-an-rss-feed-of-newest-tagged-questions/25389#25389)

what you're describing I am not sure we will do, but there is some pointlessness around "give me the 30 highest voted questions in [foo] tag" that I might add more to, later..

Comment: Hey Jeff, I was thinking more along the lines of "give me any posts that have at least 30 responses" (not the top 30 posts). For some tags I want to take more of a "read only" approach, so I just want the best Q and A's, not everything. It sounds like the "hot" designation may give a similar result. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible now thanks to a flexible little app I created called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) that converts API requests into RSS feeds.

A feed that does what you've described looks like:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions?tagged=php&sort=votes&min=20&body=true

Here's essentially what is does:

- Takes all questions tagged `'php'`.
- Sorts them by votes.
- Filters the results to only include ones with vote count >20.
- Returns the post body in the feed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very cool! I've subscribed to a few of these feeds to try them out. Thanks for posting this.