# Any way to get an RSS feed of 'newest' tagged questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, feed

The RSS feed for tagged questions returns 'hot' questions by default.  Adding `?sort=newest` to the url has no effect.

For example:

- [The newest questions tagged with 'javascript'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=javascript&sort=newest&pagesize=15)
- [The RSS feed for questions tagged with 'javascript'](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/javascript)

It would be nice for the RSS feed for a certain tag to have the same results as the page for that tag (sorted by newest or anything else).

Answer (score 4):

OK, this is now implemented -- the list by tag page has feeds specific to each tab (sort). You can find them linked at the bottom of the page, like all our other feeds.

They are labelled appropriately:

- [newest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=status-completed&sort=newest) **status-completed** questions feed
- [featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=status-completed&sort=featured) **status-completed** questions feed
- [hot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=status-completed&sort=hot) **status-completed** questions feed
- [highest voted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=status-completed&sort=votes) **status-completed** questions feed
- [recently active](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed) **status-completed** questions feed<sup>1</sup>

The highest voted is a little odd since it will be extremely static -- you'll get the top 30 voted questions in those tag(s), which isn't likely to change much over time. It makes sense as  browse order but as a top (n) rss feed I think we need a time interval specified there as well, or something. Of course doing that would make it very similar to the "hot" rss, too, so.. hm.

<sup>1</sup> this was the *only* tag based feed available before so the syntax is identical.

Comment: I searched a while for the link at the bottom of the page, until I realised that it only shows if the tab you are on has results. I think that's probably a bug, as presumably people might want to subscribe to a feed that is currently empty.

Comment: Can we get similar features on user's instead? Or it is already there?

Answer (score 1):

I bet that "sort=newest" isn't exactly what you want either, because a lot of people just don't get tagging and will put bad tags on the question initially.  I bet you still want that question to still show in your feed if it's edited the next day to have good tags and your tag is added.

Comment: Actually, it's exactly what I want.  The page for a tag sorted by newest - in a RSS feed.

Comment: I want the feature as described in the question, but I would also be somewhat interested in a (different) feature to get an RSS feed on tags that have been changed to match tags I'm now interested in.  I already monitor multiple tag sets just because people aren't good at tagging.  Feeds on searches is a better solution, but that doesn't sound likely: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches

Answer (score 1):

Use [my frontend](http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/) - I think it has the sorting ability you need, and if not, it seems to be easy to develop.

Comment: Your program looks nice, but I was looking for a RSS feed.  I can sort on SO already.

Comment: No problem. My app is (will be) capable of more things, not just the features of a regular RSS feed - actually, the list coloring, the notion of read-unread entries is quite similar to an RSS reader.