# What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?

Tags: support, feed

I know about finding the RSS feed icon at the bottom of any "Top Questions" page, giving access to [recent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds), [featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/featured), [hot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/hot), [week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/week) & [month](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/month) questions feeds. I also know that you can get RSS feeds from tags such as [support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/support) and even construct searches with [specific tag and view combination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25389/138432).

Also, I have [just discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93615/138432) that you can get [user responses feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/138432/responses) and by inference a full [user feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/138432), and even [use boolean operators on tag combinations](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/), but I don't know what other user related feeds are available.

As far as I can tell, ***Stack Exchange*** only supports the [hot questions feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions) and the [feed without questions](https://stackexchange.com/feeds) just returns the same as the *hot questions feed*. Also, Stack Exchange doesn't appear to support user feeds, which is a shame as that [*would be even more useful*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85897/138432).

So, to summarise what feeds I can identify so far:

- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/featured`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/featured))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/hot`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/hot))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/week`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/week))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/month`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/month))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag/`**tag*** (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/rss))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag/`**tag1**`+`**tag2*** (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/rss+support))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag/`**tag1**`+or+`**tag2*** (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/rss+or+support))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag/`**tag1**`+-`**tag2*** (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/rss+-support))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag**`&sort=newest`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss&sort=newest))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag**`&sort=featured`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss&sort=featured))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag**`&sort=hot`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss&sort=hot))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag**`&sort=votes`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss&sort=votes))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag1**`+`**tag2*** (+an optional `&sort=` term) (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss+support))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag1**`+or+`**tag2*** (+an optional `&sort=` term) (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss+or+support))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/tag?tagnames=`**tag1**`+-`**tag2*** (+an optional `&sort=` term) (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=rss+-support))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/user/`**user id*** (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/138432))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/user/`**user id**`/responses`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/138432/responses))
- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/question/`**question id*** (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/151519))
- *`https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions`* (
  [e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions))
- *`https://stackexchange.com/feeds`* (
  [e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds))

While the following inferred possible RSS feeds **don't** work:

- *`http://`**stack exchange site**`/feeds/votes`* (
  [e.g.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/votes))
- *`https://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`**user id*** (
  [e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/18514))

So, what other RSS feeds are available?

So far I have been unable to find any canonical list of what is available, just the occasional meta post containing partial information. So far there have been no responses to [What feeds are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136703/138432) while the [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) references a question which is no longer appears relevant (as far as I can see).

Comment: Of course the `/votes/` one doesn't work; votes are private.

Comment: @Undo, I was referring to pages such as stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes where votes is meant as "total number of votes" rather than "list of votes cast". I.e I was inferring the possibility of an RSS feed of the highest voted questions, but that makes little sense which I guess is why it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: `http://stackexchange.com/filters/` *filterid* `/` *filtername*

Comment: Whoops, I'm rolling back my edit on this. I edited out a link referring to the fact [StackExchange network profile user feeds](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/93089) don't work - I confused it for regular site feeds (e.g. [Mark Booth's Meta.SO feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/138432)) which do work. (also notifying @hjpotter92 who made an edit based on mine)

Comment: Thanks @JohannesKuhn I've added examples for my current feeds, do you have an example of how to use a `filters` feed? I haven't come across these so far.

Comment: Well, my Meta-Feed (All questions from meta.SO and Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta) or my Favs Filter (More or less things that I'm intrested in.) You can create your own filter here, at the bottom of your filter is a feed link. And you can get update emails about new questions.

Comment: Argh. Something striped out all my links.

Comment: More feed urls can be generated using stack-exchange api: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: Thanks for the link @KhurshidAlam but I can't see how I can use it to improve my question. Do you have any examples of how the API documentation relates to RSS feeds?

Comment: @Mark because you say "`http://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/user id` works for some users but not for others", and it's wrong. It doesn't work at all. You linked to http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1 which works, but it points to Stack Overflow, not Stack Exchange.  http://stackexchange.com/feeds/user/1 does not work. I understand it's a mistake done long time ago, but still - a mistake

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard , it was easier to just roll back to before the edit which broke the thing I tried to fix up. *8')

Comment: Is it possible to filter by a type of response? For example, a user's answers only?

Comment: I haven't found a way @TravisJ but if you do, please either edit in some examples, or post examples as comments and I'll incorporate them into my question.

Comment: Didn't some of those user elements change name? E.g., "recent", "featured", and "hot"

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Yes, but it looks like the corresponding feed names have not been changed.

Answer (score 14):

This is not an answer, but a way to using these feeds.

I've recently discovered [rsstail](http://www.vanheusden.com/rsstail/) and [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/), both by Folkert van Heusden.  These are utilities which allow you to create, effectively, a "tail" of an RSS feed (for rsstail), or of one or more files and/or processes (for multitail), in a terminal window.

multitail adds a bunch of additional features, including color highlighting (a bit gaudy, but configurable), scrollback, search, timestamping, and other capabilities.

Getting multitail to read, say, a whole list of feeds is a bit complicated, but I've glued up some AWK script which will create an rsstail process for each feed in my newsbeuter URLs file (newsbeuter is an interactive console RSS reader), and follow those.  More on that [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/dredmorbius/comments/1udv6i/further_adventures_in_rss_chrome_reader_extension/cek9441).

Though if you just want to follow an individual Stack Exchange question's feed, you could run something like:

```
multitail -CS rsstail -l "rsstail -l \
    -u 'http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/151519'"
```

(That will give you *this* question's feed.)

For impromptu monitoring of some specific feed or list of feeds, this is pretty handy. Since it's just running in a terminal, you don't have to remember to clear the temporary additions out of your newsreader at a later date, it's intrinsically ephemeral.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

Some more feeds of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/):

- `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/sites` ([e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/sites))
- `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/`***filter id***`/`***filter name***`?sort=active` ([e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/357906/my-sites?sort=active))
- `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/`***filter id***`/`***filter name***`?sort=newest` ([e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/357906/my-sites?sort=newest))
- `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/`***filter id***`/`***filter name***`?sort=noanswers` ([e.g.](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/357906/my-sites?sort=noanswers))

---

[Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) has slightly different feeds:

- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds`(+an optional `&category=` term) ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot`(+an optional `&category=` term) ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/progress`(+an optional `&category=` term) ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/progress))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/beta`(+an optional `&category=` term) ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/beta))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/launched`(+an optional `&category=` term) ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/launched))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`***user id*** ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/196999))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/`***proposal id*** ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/124039))

Here, `&category=`***category name*** can take one of the following options for ***category name***: `arts`, `business`, `culture`, `life`, `professional`, `recreation`, `science`, or `technology`.

The following are **not** legitimate Area 51 feeds:

- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured` ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/week` ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/week))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/month` ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/month))
- `https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/`***user id***`/responses` ([e.g.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/196999/responses))
- Any tag or question related feeds

---

The Stack Overflow blog, [The Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/), has some feeds:

- `https://stackoverflow.blog/feed` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.blog/feed))
- `https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/feed` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.blog/newsletter/feed))
- `https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3` ([e.g.](https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3)) — this is the podcast feed
- `https://stackoverflow.blog/talent/feed/` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.blog/talent/feed/))
- `https://stackoverflow.blog/talent-de/feed/` ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.blog/talent-de/feed/))

---

[Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) feeds:

- `https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/`***search string*** ([e.g.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/i+like+waffles))
- `https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/`***room number*** ([e.g.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/1))

Similar feeds exist for the chat servers of [Meta SE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).