# Get rss feed of questions that have at least one answer

Tags: support, feed

Is it possible to get a rss feed of questions that have at least one answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, I'm afraid, according to [the most exhaustive list of SE RSS feeds I could find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519/202832).

One option is to pull [the all questions feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds), then check [each individual question's feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/243453), which contains answers.

Comment: Maybe the 'hot' feed will be good enough for me :)