# Equivalent of RSS /feeds/week for a specific tag

Tags: support, tags, feed

In Stackexchange sites there is an RSS feed like`https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/week/` for each site, filtering questions more than `hot` and other available sort parameters can, what is the equivalent of that **week** feed *but* for a specific tag?

For example, for the tag `java`, something like: `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java/week/` or `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java?filter=week`?
(I've already tried most of the combinations based in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519/252564) without success).

BTW, sorting them with `?sort=hot` (like `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=hot` doesn't seems to be working, it returns the same of `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java` is it deprecated or is there a new endpoint?

Comment: &sort=newest on the end of an RSS feed doesn't work either. It returns Active questions instead of Newest. Anyone have a solution?