# Feeds in chat room throw error

Tags: support, tags, chat, feed

I am trying to add feeds to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85085/product-testing). I want feeds to update about new questions on Worldbuilding Meta with one or more of the tags I have specified. When I try to add the link below, I get an error page.

`https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=on-topic+or+close-reasons+or+vote-to-close+or+closing-questions+or+closed-questions+or+down-votes+or+reviews+or+too-broad+or+specific-answer+or+opinion-based+or+low-quality+or+reopening-questions+or+exact-duplicates+or+on-hold+or+moderation+or+deleted-questions+or+retagging+or+reviewing-behavior+or+deleting-posts&sort=newest`

I think the problem is either that I am using incorrect syntax in the link or the link has too many tags. When I remove some of the tags, it works, but it seems like if I add certain tags to that it gives me the error. That makes me think it has something to do with the tags themselves.

What I am trying to do is get only one feed update per question. If I put all of the tags in separate links, and there is an update to a question with more than one of these tags, I will get multiple updates, right?

Comment: For reference, I used [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its) to figure out how to format the links.