# Are the "hidden" RSS feeds at risk of going away?

Tags: support, questions, feed

There's a [list of hidden RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its) from 2012. I believe that some of these feeds also offer alternative sorts.

The reason I ask is because I'm thinking about subscribing to new question feeds using a service that converts an RSS feed to email for entire sites. There are some services that will access an RSS feed on a regular basis and convert new posts to emails. Ideally, I wouldn't have to use this service, but there hasn't been much work done to help improve the discoverability of questions that I, as an expert in certain topics, can answer across the network. However, I'm concerned that because these are "hidden" and the links to them are non-obvious in the UI, that they may be deprecated without warning, putting me right back to where I am.

---

I'd also like to throw out the idea that if the RSS feeds aren't in danger of going away that they are made more obvious on the views that they relate to. For example, in the Questions view, I'd expect to see a reference or link to the RSS feed that exists for that view (including any applied sorting). I believe that this would give me more confidence in the fact that they won't be going away.

Comment: Most of those feeds aren't hidden, and are linked to with an RSS icon somewhere near the bottom of the relevant page or in its sidebar. I think we lost a handful of those links in the resdesign for question filters (though they definitely were there before), but that's just a matter of making sure the links get added back at some point. E.g. the feed for *this question* is linked in the sidebar under Hot Network Questions.

Comment: @animuson That is...a non obvious place to put that one - I would not look under "Hot Network Questions" for the feed of activity on this particular question. But also consider [this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest) - I don't see a feed link here at all, but maybe this was impacted by the redesign of question filters. I'm definitely concerned by the non-obviousness of the existence of feeds and what this means for their maintenance.

Comment: Ok, so we never had RSS feeds at `/questions`. Most of the ones at the top of the "hidden" list actually correspond to the tabs available at the homepage (`/`) question lists. The RSS link used to appear at the very bottom of the list of questions floating to the right, but got moved to the sidebar as well with the redesign.

Comment: @animuson So it seems like the question is still valid: For the feeds that exist but that don't have a link (such as `/questions`), are these feeds at risk of being deprecated without warning?

Comment: I don't believe there *is* a feed for `/questions` on sites. The `/questions` feed in that list refers to the lists available at stackexchange.com, which is also linked. I believe the entire list available in that question were ones he found by links on the site - no one ever answered with any hidden, unlinked feeds. So no, you shouldn't worry about them going away if we still link them everywhere.

Comment: @animuson, I always figured the "question feed" at the bottom of HNQ was an RSS feed of HNQ.

Comment: @animuson I've been playing around with this. Either I'm misunderstanding what you are saying or I'm not communicating my question clearly. `https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest` is a feed. As far as I can tell after watching it for a while, this corresponds exactly to `https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest`. Yet as far as I can tell, the feed is not linked to anywhere. So I'm concerned that I will start to rely on this feed (and similar feeds) and they will just go away someday. I also don't see this or any similar feed on stackexchange.com.