# Notification for specific user's answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, answers, notifications

I know that if I follow a question, I am notified if the question receives an answer. I am also notified for every single comment, edit, close, etc.

I see some users who are actually good contributors. Most of the time, they provide answers to valuable questions. Also, they generally do not ask questions.

**Feature Request:**

For example, as I think user (M.x) is a good contributor on Stack Overflow, I want to be notified of all his answers, give us the ability to follow specific users' answers.

I don't know about the possibility to implement that feature or about the complexity.

**For study purpose, would it be helpful?**

**Personal Opinion:** I  think it will be helpful for me.

**Note:**

I know there is a way for everyone to see all questions/answers and also without logging in. Also, I know If I go to one user's profile and vote on his questions/answers, that's serial voting and will be reversed and both accounts can be banned. Also, anyone can say that you can bookmark the user's profile and check their answers every day.

**Why?**

But notification is different. It will remind the user that you have something new you can read/learn now. If anyone thinks this way, it will be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A "friends list" on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice) See also: [Add a feature to follow a user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260700/8967612) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: if it's unwanted, why `RSS feeds` does this job something like this ? ... I think it's your personal opinion ... also read Journeyman Geek♦'s answer below and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360311/user-rss-feeds-should-include-post-type-tags-and-tags-for-answers)

Comment: With three dozen answers on the banners's duplicate's and agreement upon the closure it not my personal opinion. **DON'T** reply to automated answers and question the decision with ***one*** reviewer; it's a group decision.

Comment: @Rob you wrote something like, _unwanted for rest of people._ I mentioned that, it was your personal opinion and not for duplicate issue. maybe it's  misunderstanding,  okay.

Answer (score 7):

SE has a whole load of ‘hidden’ RSS feeds including ones for the user page.

If you go to say https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/738249/noor?tab=answers and add it to your favourite rss feed reader it will turn into an RSS feed of the form https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/738249.

While this includes questions and comments- you may be able to use this to keep track of a user's posts (maybe including some filters for questions) and tie it into your notification system of choice.

Comment: I write about it that, _I can bookmark user profile and check every day their answers_ in my note,  notification is different thing

Comment: You can tie an RSS feed into a notification system - say a slack bot or even an rss feed reader. Its a remarkably powerful tool in the right hands - and a bit of an elegant tool for a more civilised age. Heck, I got to 10k on SU with the help of an RSS feed to the main page. In a sense - going to the user page is *polling*. RSS feeds 'pull' new content so you don't have to check manually. The idea is you can feed some notification system on your platform of choice the things you're interested in, filter them and get what you need

Comment: sorry for first comment, i got it, `RSS` is others notification tools, thanks..

Comment: _RSS_  all posts automatic update is not free... i need to upgrade pro version ..

Comment: uhhh.... I don't pay anything for RSS feeds. Its a standard with multiple clients.

Comment: actually I was installed  a google chrome extension . there was a feature _posts automatic update_ . this is not free.., By the way I need to try it other way or  take time to understand how it works and used to it ... thanks ...

Comment: The canonical may or may not be *[What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519)*.