# Is it possible to create an RSS feed of the latest answers for a certain tag?

Tags: feature-request, answers, feed

I want to create a feed for user activity that will give me the recent questions and answers.

I was able to create a feed for new questions with this script:

```
import feedparser

# Set the RSS feed URLs for questions and answers
questions_rss_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python"


# Keep track of the most recent post and answer IDs
most_recent_post_id = None
most_recent_answer_id = None

while True:
    # Get the RSS feeds for questions and answers
    questions_feed = feedparser.parse(questions_rss_url)

    # Check each question in the questions feed
    for question in questions_feed.entries:
        # Check if the question is newer than the most recent one we've seen
        if most_recent_post_id is None or question.id != most_recent_post_id:
            # If it's a new question, do something with it (in this case, just print the title)
            print("New question: ", question.title)

            # Update the most recent question ID
            most_recent_post_id = question.id
```

but I'm still not sure how to retrieve the latest answers.
Is it possible?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360311/user-rss-feeds-should-include-post-type-tags-and-tags-for-answers would be one approach which hasn't happened

Comment: Script in what context? E.g., where does it run? A Python script?

Comment: yes a python script that runs on an ec2 machine

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests

# Set the API endpoint and parameters
api_url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/{question_id}/answers"
params = {"order": "desc", "sort": "activity", "site": "stackoverflow"}

# Set the question ID for which you want to retrieve answers
question_id = "1234567"  # replace with the actual question ID

# Send the API request
response = requests.get(api_url.format(question_id=question_id), params=params)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Extract the answer data from the API response
    answer_data = response.json()["items"]
    
    # Check each answer in the answer data
    for answer in answer_data:
        # Print the answer ID and text
        print("Answer ID:", answer["answer_id"])
        print("Answer text:", answer["body"])
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve answers:", response.status_code)
```

Comment: this returns answers for a single question, not for a tag.