# How can I browse popular questions of multiple communities?

Tags: feature-request, support

I have joined more than 15 communities on Stack Exchange.

One of the things I enjoy is going to *Questions* → *More* → *Score* and seeing the most upvoted questions.

A lot of them are really interesting and they could make a good book.

Therefore, I wonder if there is a website/place where we could get a "feed" experience to browse the most popular questions of our communities and enjoy reading their answers?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. You _could_ do a [search on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+score%3A100+answers%3A3) for, say,`is:q score:100 answers:3` which delivers, alphabetically by site, 60k questions that have a 100+ score and at least 3 answers. But that's huge, probably not fun to sift through.

Comment: Hot Network Posts sidebar is the best way honestly.

Answer (score 2):

I thought RSS feeds might come to the rescue, but I dug and dug and dug through [the various options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519), but didn't find any one solution that perfectly fits what you're looking for.

Here are the things I found that are sorta close:

- Feed of *active* questions from all sites where you have an account

  - `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/${filterId}/my-sites?sort=active`
  - To find your specific filter feed URL, you'll need to go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/my-sites, and then copy the URL from the link that's at the bottom of the page, to the right of the pagination buttons:

    - [image: Location of "My Sites feed" link on https://stackexchange.com/filters/my-sites]
- Feed of a single site's ["hot" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot):

  - `https://${site}/feeds/hot`
- Feed of "hot" questions from (all?) sites across the Network:

  - `https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions`

The only kind of feed I found sortable directly by score is the site-specific tag feed, unfortunately, which isn't super useful for surveying multiple sites:

- `http://${site}/feeds/tag?tagnames=${tag-or-+tags}&sort=votes`

Of these, I think the closest thing might be either the Network-wide hot question feed, or using a feed reader to group together individually selected site-specific hot question feeds together, though I realize this isn't exactly what you're looking for.